# Signing the binaries to set up the solution to give a different version number in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, msbuild, versioning, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor WebAssembly and the requirement is to set up the solution to give a different version number, how does this work and what are the steps that we need to follow?

I have tried with updating the .csproj file and by adding an environment variable

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(APPVERSION)' == ''">
 <InformationalVersion>1.0.0.0</InformationalVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(APPVERSION)' != ''">
  <InformationalVersion>$(APPVERSION)</InformationalVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

But how will it auto increment the version?

Comment: That would be a good question for people following the visual-studio or msbuild tags. Or maybe github-actions

Comment: Your build process or system will increment the version. You may find what I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75626134/where-should-i-store-project-related-properties-in-visual-studio-2022-assembl/75653410#75653410) to be helpful.

Comment: @JonathanDodds, thank you for your response. I tried it and I am getting the below error for the import in the Directory.Build.props file => MSB4020 The value "" of the "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid. Is there anything that I am missing?